# Create an array object from string array

Tags: arrays, json, swift

I have an array of string which has x amount of elements and x >= 2

```
let arrayOfString = ["A", "B"]
// or
let arrayOfString = ["A", "B", "C", ...]
```

and I want to use the arrayOfString to create an object array in this format

```
[
    {
        "option": "A"
    },
    {
        "option": "B"
    },
    ...
]
```

I have tried to create a struct like this

```
    struct PollOptionArray {
    let option: String
}
```

and loop through the string array

```
var pollDetailArray = [PollOptionArray]()

      for index in arrayOfString {
             pollDetailArray.append(PollOptionArray(option: index)
       }
```

but I think it is wrong
Can anyone give me a suggestion? Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple map will work:

```
let objectArray = arrayOfString.map { [ "option" : $0 ] }
```

Or, based on your `struct`:

```
let pollDetailArray = arrayOfString.map { PollOptionArray(option: $0) }
```

Comment: What do you think about my method?

Comment: I just updated based on your `struct` (which wasn't in the question when I first answered). Your code works just fine if you want to create an array of struct. The `map` in my answer gives the same result.

Comment: Oh cool. Lastly, is there a way that I can ignore empty string because in my string array, sometimes it is  ["A", "", "B"] and I want to ignore that empty string. Thanks!

Comment: Filter the array: `let pollDetailArray = arrayOfString.filter { !$0.isEmpty }.map { PollOptionArray(option: $0) }`